# How do I connect these modules to an arduino?

Tags: arduino

I am trying to connect three components to my Arduino Uno: a [Wave Shield](http://www.ladyada.net/make/waveshield/), an [LCD Screen](http://www.coolcomponents.co.uk/catalog/blue-16x2-display-p-151.html) and a [keypad](http://babelduck.com/index.php/en/reference/user-manuals/1424-matrix-keypad-user-manual).

There are not enough ports for all these modules and I am wondering how I can extend the Uno.  Do I have to buy an extra part? Or can I use a breadboard to use the ports on the Uno for more than one component?

Comment: Please add some links to the various parts.

Comment: Edited main post with them

Comment: This question is too vague with much missing information.  It's a arduino user question at best, not about electronics.

Answer (score 2):

A brief pin consumption summary:

- The Wave Shield consumes eight pins (D2, D3, D4, D5, D10, D11, D12,
  and D13)
- You need eight pins to scan a 4x4 keypad.
- You need six pins
  to talk to an LCD like the one you've linked to.

That's a total of 8 + 8 + 6 = 22 pins. The Arduino has 21 GPIO pins. So I think you simply do not fit on the device. If you can compromise on hardware, one solution for you would be to use a Serial LCD module like [this one](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9877) at SparkFun, which minimally consumes only one pin (D1).

Comment: http://wingshieldindustries.com/products/screwshield/ Should be able to extend it , got it thanks

Comment: Or you could bit-bang one of the devices over a shift register to save yourself a bunch of pins.

Comment: Or he could use one line less to connect a keypad (and loose some keys).

Comment: @HenryHoggard the screwshield does not add any additional I/O pins to your Arduino...

Comment: @Polynomial yes but I presumed he wouldn't want to add additional hardware and software complexity to the system... I'm guessing he wants to use library-ready parts, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @avra yes that is an alternative, if he doesn't need all 16 keys he could give up a row or column. I assumed that was not an option either.

Comment: I suppose i could buy a bigger arduino if i have to?

Comment: @HenryHoggard Yes you would have tons of extra I/O if you used an Arduino Mega2560 for example.